# Making CRUD for a resource with one-to-one relationships on Backback for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, one-to-one, laravel-backpack

Imagine a *User*-model that is associated with one *Phone*-model as a one-to-one relationship as defined by [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), meaning that the *User*-model has a function:

```
/**
 * Get the phone record associated with the user.
 */
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
}
```

while the *Phone*-model has a function:

```
/**
 * Get the user that owns the phone.
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

The question is now how to make a CRUD controller in **Backpack for Laravel**, which makes is possible to add a new *User* where the *Phone* is also provided in the same CRUD add/edit form.

It seems to be standard that you add a Phone resource and then add a User resource where there is a select-field where you can choose an existing Phone resources, but instead I am trying to add a new User with a new Phone in one CRUD controller, and also editing a User while at the same time editing his Phone.

Here are two examples of how it could look:
[Illustration of Backpack Add-form for a User-model with a one-to-one relation to the Phone-model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qzmn.png)

I hope this makes sense.

EDIT: It would appear that this is not possible using the current version of Backpack for Laravel, but that work on adding this features is on the way: [Github - Feature 1 to 1 relationships #865](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/865)

Answer (score 1):

Just write over the updateCrud and storeCrud functions and write your own logic. This is very simple logic to write. You can just update the user with the rest of the fields, then update the phone field manually.

You can also try adding a getPhoneAttribute and setPhoneAttribute to your User model. These functions could manage the relationship and Backpack would never know it isn't just another attribute.

This is all possible in Backpack, just need to write some logic yourself

Comment: This does not really solve the problem. Let us say that there is an attribute "number" in the Phone-model. That can easily be accessed through $user->phone->number without having defined any accessors. I can of cause assign an accessor so that the number is returned as $user->phonenumber and that phonenumber can be shown in Backpack. BUT if you try to add the Column "phone" in the UserCrudController, then you see that the phone model is shown json encoded. But HOW to access the fields from the phone model?

Comment: @user3390352 you write a `getPhoneAttribute` function that shows `$this->phone->number`

Answer (score 0):

there are many options
$user->phone()->save($phone)

Comment: But I am looking for a solution that works with Backpack for Laravel.